# Electron app not seeing updates in the installed application

Tags: windows-installer, electron

Firstly here is the GitHub repo because this code is too large to paste into here, https://github.com/HolyBreadstick/Electron-Hello-World/tree/master/AngularProfile-Page

Alright onto my question:
So I have been following about a hundred different blog posts on how to setup an electron app. I can very easily get my app running on my system with a command I created called `npm run electron-dev`. When doing this I can see that changes are being applied to my application. Now I have followed a guide on how to create the package for my electron app, sadly though I think I messed a step up within this.

1. Firstly, I created a secondary package.json file within my src folder that has some metadata within it. What's the point of this file if my createInstaller.js has some of the same metadata.
2. I created a script called `npm run windows-installer` which is a way of calling all my major build scripts and packager. If I run this after making a change to anything in my view code, when the installer script completes I run the setup.exe file and notice that none of my changes have been applied.
3. I thought I followed a guide on how to setup the installer events for creating the shortcut icon and so on, that step never worked because I don't see an icon in my start menu.

I understand that this question is a bit broad I am having trouble narrowing it down because I am not finding good guides that lay out the whole process for creating, packaging, installing, updating an electron app for windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there are many different ways of packaging/building electron apps (all of these are cross-platform as well):

- Electron Packager- pretty basic and mostly from the command line
- Electron Builder- a little more advanced but very customizable
- Electron Forge- gives you a nice template to get started with packaging already implemented. I think that's your best bet

I would recommend looking at all of those and finding one that best fits your project.

I would also recommend looking at other people's projects and looking at what they do. [Awesome Electron](https://github.com/sindresorhus/awesome-electron) Is a great resource for finding projects.

But for your questions:

1. Putting a `package.json` in the src gives electron-builder metadata and dependency info, and what you have in your createInstaller.js is giving electron-winstaller metadata
2. This might be a problem with the version number. Try Updating the version number
3. Looking at this [blog post](https://www.christianengvall.se/electron-packager-tutorial/) might help with the icon problem

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue while using electron js + react js.
Those who are generating applications by using **npm run dist** command use **npm run build** command it will resolve your latest code update issue.